# Brouwer's Fixed Point theorem proof for 2-dimension

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, self-learning

I am trying to find a elementary proof of the Brouwer's fixed point theorem only using basics of point set topology and real analysis. In the one of the textbooks I read, they were proving Brouwer's fixed point theorem for n = 2 the following way:

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be compact and convex. Then consider the map $T:K \to K$, have no fixed points. Now define $F:K \to \partial K$ as follows. For $x \in K$, form a line segment connecting $x$ and $T(x)$, Let $F(x)$ be the point where the line segment intersection the boundary $\partial K$

Now if $T(x) \in \partial K$ then let $F(x)$ equal that intersection point of the ray with $\partial K$ which is not equal to $T(x)$ (The above set up makes sense).

Then they define $F(x) = \dfrac{Tx - x}{\| Tx - x\|}$ (How is this a retraction?), they claim this is a continuous function without proof (what would be the approach of proof here, which definition of continuity should I try?). After this they just say it contradicts the no retraction theorem (result of Sperner's lemma, that's fine).

I would like to get clarification with this proof.

Comment: You can use "\partial K" for boundary notation $\partial K$, FYI.

Comment: @MPW thanks I edited it

Comment: Note that $||F||=1$. $F$ is continuous since $T$ is. It is allowed to divice by $||Tx-x||$ since there are no fixed points. Hence $F:K\to S^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most elementary analytic proof (as opposed to algebro-geometric) is the one of Milnor-Rogers - Actually, it is Rogers proof, which simplifies the one of Milnor - See [proof](http://www.math.sc.edu/~howard/Notes/brouwer.pdf).

As you don't seem to mind Algebraic Geometry, you can do the proof of Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem in 2-D just using the fact that the fundamental group of $S^1$ is $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I will check his proof out. Could you gave me clarification on the proof I presented above?